# class not found Symfony 3.0

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar, symfony

currently i'm developping a project with the framework symfony in order to use a calendar with events.
So i decide to use this bundle that is close to what i want : https://github.com/adesigns/calendar-bundle

I'm trying to launch a service in order to load my events in my calendar but i have some trouble to find my class.
This is the error that i have :
[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nU7Ft.png)

this is where i declare my service : 
    parameters:
    #    parameter_name: value

```
services:
#    service_name:
#        class: AppBundle\Directory\ClassName
#        arguments: ["@another_service_name", "plain_value", "%parameter_name%"]

projetTest.calendartestbundle.calendar_listener:
    class: projetTest\calendartestBundle\EventListener\CalendarEventListener
    arguments:  ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: calendar.load_events, method: loadEvents }
```

There is my view who call the template calendar :

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
{% block title %}
Projet test calendar
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
<h1>Projet test calendar</h1>
{% include 'ADesignsCalendarBundle::calendar.html.twig' %}
{% endblock %}
```

So i need your helps guys if someone have an idea i would like to hear it thank you.

Comment: did you clear the cache? Did you register the bundle?

Comment: Yea i clear the cache and yes i register the bundle

Answer (score 0):

The first you should know is that a namespace should always be in upper camel case: instead of `projetTest\calendartestBundle\EventListener\CalendarEventListener`, you should use `ProjetTest\CalendarTestBundle\EventListener\CalendarEventListener`.

For your problem, it seems your class can't be found, which is a problem of autoloading. Autoloading is usually handled by Composer in Symfony so there are two possible problems:

- the file where Composer is looking for your class (`src/projetTest/calendartestBundle/EventListener/CalendarEventListener.php`) does not exists ;
- the class `CalendarEventListener` is not present in this file or not under the right namespace ;

Comment: Ok i'm gonna try this, yea sometimes I made mistake when i named a bundle how can rename it safely ?

Comment: Well my namespace was bad i had src/calendartestBundle/EventListener/
So i change into src/projetTest/calendartestBundle/EventListener and now is working, i don't have my events but this is another bug i guess.